# Can Podman change host environments per container or does it behave exactly like Docker?

Tags: environment-variables, podman

I'm learning Podman so I apologize for silly mistakes.

Docker Redis has a [notorious problem](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/issues/165) where the database might fail to write if in the container `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` is not set to 1 (the default value is 0).

I know that Podman doesn't use a Daemon and I thought that this could allow it to set specific host environmental values per container (Docker doesn't allow this -- one must change the host variables and then all containers being created will copy them; thus, if you set a different value for the host environmental variables it will be applied to *all* subsequent containers, there's no way to apply it only to a specific one).

The [documentation](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-run.1.html) says that, for `--env`, "--env: Any environment variables specified will override previous settings". But alas, I think it behaves identically to Docker and doesn't allow one to change host env per container. I tried `podman run .... --env 'overcommit_memory=1'` and it made no difference at all. I guess this approach would only make sense for general environmental variables and not for specific `vm` ones.

But I was curious: **is it possible at all to change host env per container in Podman?** And in specific, is there any way to change `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` per container?

---

EDIT: can `podman play kube` be of any help?

EDIT2: one might wonder why I don't encapsulate the `podman run` command with `echo 1 > overcommit_memory` and afterwards revert to `echo 0 > overcommit_memory`, but I need to use a Windows machine to develop this and I think this wouldn't be possible

EDIT 3: Eureka! <del>Found a solution</del> [**not really, see criztovyl's answer**] to my original problem, I just need create a dir (say, `mkdir vm`), add a `overcommit_memory` file to it with content equal to `1`, and add to the `podman run` instruction `-v vm:/proc/sys/vm:rw`. This way a volume is bound to the container in `rw` mode and rewrites the value of `overcommit_memory`. But I'm still curious as to whether there's a more straightforward way to change that env

EDIT 4: Actually, `COPY init.sh` is the best option so far https://r-future.github.io/post/how-to-fix-redis-warnings-with-docker/ [**again, not really, see criztovyl's answer below**]

Comment: Does `--sysctl` not do what you want? Oh, and I don't think `overcommit_memory` is a per-container thing anyway - rather it's a host-level setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Richard says, it does not seem to be currently possible to set `vm.overcommit_memory` per-container, you must set it at the host via `sysctl` (not `--sysctl`).

This applies to both Podman and Docker, as for the "actual" container they both in the end rely on the same kernel APIs (cgroups).

---

Note that you say "changing the host env", which can be misinterpreted as changing the host's environment variables. Overwriting environment variables is possible as you tried with `--env`.

But memory overcommit is a *kernel* parameter which you must set via `sysctl`, not environment variables.

Certain sysctl options are overwriteable via `--sysctl`, but `vm.overcommit_memory` is, as far as i can tell, no such option.

---

Regarding your first edit: `kube play` only is a fancy way to "import" pods/containers described in kubernetes yaml format. in the end it does not set different options you could not also use manually.

Regarding your second edit: I dont think for development you need to toggle it, it should be okay to just keep it enabled. Or keep it disabled altogether because during development the warning and potential failing writes should be acceptable.

Your option 3 only *silences* the warning, but the database write can still fail, it only makes it appear to redis overcomitting is enabled, but actually overcommit is still disabled.

Your option 4 works with a *privileged* container, enabling overcommit *for the whole host*. As such it is a convenience option for when you can run privileged containers (eg during development), but it will fail when you cannot run privileged (eg in production).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Just to be absolutely clear, by needing to use `sysctl` instead of `--sysctl` you mean one needs to change this setting in the host, right? (By running `sysctl` in the host) Or is it a different Docker function/argument? And are you sure that option 3 only silences the warning? When I entered the container via bash and queried the read-only `overcommit_memory`, it was set to 1 as desired. Is this because if the host doesn't enable `overcommit_memory`, it's irrelevant what the container sets? (i.e. container memory is managed by the host, not the container)

Comment: Yes, with `sysctl` I mean the command in the host.

Comment: I am sure about option 3. When you check the file in the container you actually check your volume-mounted file. The mounted file overlays the file from the underlying `procfs`, without changing it. That is the reason why you see the expected `1`, but from perspective of the host kernel nothing changed, thus saying the container did "set" something is a wrong expression. Also generally the container "manages" nothing, its all the host kernel :)